# StringBuilder или + в цикле

Tags: java

```
String str="";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    str+="я";
}
```

это правда, что вот этот код превращается компилятором в этот:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    sb.append("я");
}
```

Если это так, есть ли смысл использовать второй вариант? Ведь первый более читаем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почитайте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132241/).

```
//медленно
String[] fields = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    s = s + fields[i];
}
return s;

//быстро
String[] fields = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    s.append(fields[i]);
}
return s.toString();
```

> Никогда не используйте операции конкатенации (оператор +) строки в
>   цикле, особенно если таких операций у вас много, это может очень
>   существенно снизить производительность. Все это происходит потому, что
>   в приведенном выше примере «s = s + fileds[i]» выполняется целых 3
>   операции: создается StringBuilder на основе строки s, вызывается метод
>   конкатенации append, после конкатенации вызывается метод toString
>   (выглядит так: s = new
>   StringBuilder(s).append(fields[i]).toString();). Целых 3 операции
>   вместо одной! Помимо этого каждый результат s + fileds[i] будет
>   занимать память в куче, как отдельная строка.

Так что ответ на ваш вопрос такой: да, есть смысл использовать `StringBuilder` вместо конкатенации.

Comment: видел какой-то из докладов Шипилева, и он там приводил пример, когда быстрее будет + использовать. Хотя возможно, я не так интерпретировал

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, возможно, это был про итераторы?)
http://automation-remarks.com/nieskolko-prostykh-optimizatsii-proizvoditielnosti-java/

Answer (score 1):

В первом варианте, цикл создаст count строк, которые возможно, будут удалены сборщиком мусора, что не есть хорошо.Второй случай гораздо лучше, так как не создает новый объект, как это делает String, а добавляет нужные символы в существующую строку, что экономит память и предотвращает возможность удаления сборщиком мусора.Настоятельно рекомендую использовать его.Но стоит помнить что этот класс не синхронизирован, поэтому не стоит использовать его в мультипоточных приложениях, а заменять его классом StringBuffer, который практически идентичен StringBuilder'у, только немного медленнее.