# Как перенести ответ в консоли в String для дальнейшего его использования в Java?

Tags: java, строки

```java
public class Hw2Task5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        String number = scan.nextLine();
  
        String change;
        for (int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(number.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно `number.charAt(i)` занести в `String change`, что бы значение переменной `change` можно было использовать в другом методе.

Comment: Это называется присваивание и даже присутствует в этом коде.

Comment: Сначала надо написать другой метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как отмечено в комментарии, чтобы "занести" `number.charAt(i)` в переменную `change`, следует использовать присваивание, но перед этим переменная `change` должна быть проинициализирована пустой строкой:

```java
String change = "";
for (int i = number.length(); i-- > 0;) {
    change += number.charAt(i);
}
```

Но такой способ получения строки, записанной в обратном порядке, НЕ рекомендуется (см. [`StringBuilder` или `+` в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564720/)), так как используется конкатенация в цикле.
Для решения такой задачи оптимальней всего использовать метод [`StringBuilder::reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--).

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your number");
String number = scan.nextLine();

String change = new StringBuilder(number).reverse().toString();
```

---

Если же метод `reverse` запрещён, то всё равно лучше использовать `StringBuilder` для работы с *изменяемой* строкой:

- аналог первоначального решения, обычное добавление символов в обратном порядке

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number.length()); // зарезервировать размер
for (int i = number.length(); i-- > 0;) {
    sb.append(number.charAt(i));
}
String change = sb.toString(); // получить перевёрнутую строку
```

- "быстрое" решение при помощи обмена символов в начале и конце исходной строки с использованием метода [`StringBuilder::setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-):

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number); // зарезервировать размер
for (int i = 0, j = number.length(); i < --j; i++) {
    char c = sb.charAt(i);
    sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(j));
    sb.setCharAt(j, c);
}
String change = sb.toString(); // получить перевёрнутую строку
```

Comment: Хорошее объяснение! Разобрался. Спасибо!